# CSS color property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I am having some trouble changing the color property of a link when its class is changed. Here is the code

```
<div id="information">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Administration</span><small>Learn Site Administration</small></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Management</span><small>Learn Access Management</small></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Dashboard</span><small>Learn Dashboard Functions</small></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Visitors</span><small>Learn Visitor Management</small></a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the html code i am using to create my list with no inline style or anything else.

Now here is my css.

```
#information {
width: 1000px;
height: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
background:url(../images/information-bg.jpg) no-repeat 25px 5px;
}
#information ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#information ul.pagination{
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:246px;
    height:350px;
    background:url(../images/pagination-bg.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}
#information ul.pagination li {
    padding:5px 0 0 5px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}
#information ul.pagination li a {
    width:270px;
    height:85px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left -85px;
    background-image:url(../images/thumb-sprite.png);
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    color: #464646;
}
#information ul.pagination li.current a {
    background-position:left top;
    color: white;
}
#information ul.pagination li a span {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 0 0 0;
}
#information ul.pagination li a small {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#428301;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right -80px;
    background-image:url(../images/arrows.gif);
    padding:0 17px 0 0;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#information ul.pagination li.current a small {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #89C100;
    background-position:right 5px;
}
#information ul.pagination li a span, #information ul.pagination li a small {
    padding-left:40px;
}
```

Currently no element have a class .current so I add class to first element through script and , here is the script

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    //Adding class to pagination and showing first image
    var currentPagination = $("ul.pagination li:eq(0)").addClass("current");
    var currentslide = $("ul.slides li:eq(0)").fadeIn(2000);    


    //On click of pagination link, changing background of pagination and anmating new slide
    $("ul.pagination li").click(function (){           
        currentPagination.removeClass("current");        
        currentPagination = $(this).addClass("current");              
        var ul = $(this).parent();
        var index = ul.children().index(this);
    });

});
```

The dilemma here is that, the background of the li with class = current is changing correctly but the color property of the element is not changing, which you can see in css property of `( #information ul.pagination li.current a )`, i dont know whats wrong with it, but i have been stuck for so long finally i decided to ask of forum.

Please note that the script is working fine because background is changing perfectly. Even at the start of webpage li with current class has the color #fff but it doesnt work afterwards, any help will be much appreciated.

P.S Here is the URL in which you can see it works fine at start but after that background image positioning changes but color does not

[image]

Comment: It is working.  See http://jsfiddle.net/zdJ4E/

Comment: do you have an public link to the background image `../images/thumb-sprite.png`?

Comment: looks fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YtjSU/1/

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/4fvmoo/8 , but not on browser. I am getting so mad at this now.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have added the tinypic url please check through it and I have also commented with the problem image in the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

Its working perfectly. as you can see in JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/banded_krait/m9kV9/1/

if it's still not working in your code try to put `!important` to that css.

```
#information ul.pagination li.current a {
    background-position:left top;
    color: red !important;
}
```

for the subtitle color put this css

```
#information ul.pagination li.current a small {
    color: red !important;
}
```

I also updated my jsfiddle. please see.
I changed the color from white to red to see that it's working or not.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/4fvmoo/8 , I have added the important it isnt working either, why the color is not working when the background image positioning is changing. !important is not necessary here.

Comment: I updated my answer. hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: you don't need to put !important if it's not necessary. I did it because it may overwrite with your other css.

Comment: li.current small 's color is already fine. using !important is not a good practice. since I can change it without !important why are you forcing it. Its not necessray becuase its not overiding anything. If its working fine on fiddle, why isnt it working in browser.

Comment: try to refresh your browser with `ctrl+F5` in case if browser cache don't let you see your changes.

Comment: you can use jquery to change the color of those text. But I don't know why it's not working. I can figure out the problem if you give me public url of your site.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmt2/1/)**

I have added

```
#information ul.pagination li.current a {
    background-position:left top;
    background-color: black; 
    color: white;
}
```

So that it is easily visible

**Updated Answer**
try to override the default link color by specifying the following property

```
#information ul.pagination li.current a:active{ 
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/4fvmoo/8 , please visit this link so that you can know better about the issue. I have tried it.

Comment: Yes. I saw that link but I am unable to recreate the issue.

Comment: the code i posted in this post is the copy paste which I am using in my app. Stuck so bad i guess.

Comment: I used Chrome's developer tools to see if `color: red;` property sets at any point. But in my case it does not.

Comment: There might be some code or style that sets the property `color: red;`. Can you look up for that using Chrome's developer tool?

Comment: nope if I change the property to color:green; it will do the same thing with jsut green color. The problem is while it is working first time , why not next time. And the only problem is with the color property not with the background-position property. Since its changing perfectly.

and I changed it to red so that you can see it clear.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if it works.

Comment: unfortunately its still a no. Well the point to note here is there everyother property is working perfectly fine only color:white; is not working :(

Comment: Then it seems that you are missing something, some property maybe, which is leading to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#information ul.pagination li.current a {
    background-position:left top;
    color: red;
}
```

your code is working fine , the thing is you are using     `color: white;`

so link is not showing .

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/4fvmoo/8, please check this, I also did it in fiddle and it worked there , but its not working in the browser. Please see the attached image for the problem, I have changed color to red for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7A3hH/)

```
$("document").ready(function(){

//Adding class to pagination and showing first image
var currentPagination = $("ul.pagination li:eq(0)").addClass("current");
var currentslide = $("ul.slides li:eq(0)").fadeIn(2000);    


//On click of pagination link, changing background of pagination and anmating new slide
$("ul.pagination li").click(function (){           
    currentPagination.removeClass("current");        
    currentPagination = $(this).addClass("current");              
    var ul = $(this).parent();
    var index = ul.children().index(this);
});

});
```

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/4fvmoo/8 , please check this, I also did it in fiddle and it worked there , but its not working in the browser. Please see the attached image for the problem, I have changed color to red for clarification.